# Converting date formats in PHP

Tags: php

I have a date:

```
20-01-2013
```

I need it to be in a format for the database:

```
2013-01-20 20:39:39
```

So far I have this:

```
$originalDate = "20-01-2013";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate));
```

But how do I get the time added to the end? I just want it to be 00:00:00.

Thanks

Comment: if you already have the `yyyy-mm-dd` portion and you know that your time is going to be zero, why not just append the string `' 00:00:00'` to the end of your existing string?

Comment: @Spudley He/She does not have a `yyyy-mm-dd` date format.

Comment: Please note that all the answers to this question are wrong. You should be using the format `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` to get 24 hour time format. Fwiw, I would have used: `$yourDate = '20-01-2013'; $date = new DateTime($yourDate); echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`, but as others have said, this question has been answered before. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do it like this?

```
$originalDate = "20-01-2013";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($originalDate)).' 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are one step away from solution you just need to insert `h:i:s` in your `date()` function, so please try this:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));
```

or either append the string

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: This will get 12 hour format time, so is incorrect.

Comment: Great :) Didn't want people finding this and getting confused!

Answer (score 0):

$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));

read more about [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: You should read the link yourself - `h` gets 12 hour format - not 24 hour.

Comment: @LeonardChallis thanks. Actually i knew but trying to give answer fast so :)